# Firebase loading snapshots issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase as a database for messaging purpose.

1. My First issue in `observeEventType:`-block. It is called multiple times frequently and I don't know when to stops activity indicator.
2. Another issue is `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` hangs my view till all the Firebase snapshots do not load. The purpose is to scroll down to the last row of table view. Please help.

Is there anything in Firebase database query to know how much count is on Firebase database?

```
    firRef = [[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:childLocation];

    [firRef keepSynced:YES];

     fireDBHandler = [firRef observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded 
    withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

     NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *messageDic =  snapshot.value;

    [self.clientTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath 
    indexPathForRow:[messages count]-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest reading [working with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) as it explains how the events work.

Digging into your code a bit here are some observations:

You are using a ChildAdded event and the docs state

> This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again
>   every time a new child is added to the specified path.

So if you have 10 child nodes, that block will be called 10 times in a row, once for each child. Based on your code, it's going to attempt to scroll for each child which is not necessary.

There are a couple of solutions.

If you are loading a series of users, you can use a single event of Value. That will read in all of the nodes at one time to which you can then iterate over the nodes, populate your datasource (usually an array) and then simply scroll to the last index.

```
[ref observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:
             ^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    //it is here we iterate over each node in the snapshot
    //and add the data to an array dataSource.

  } withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

another option is to leverage the fact that Value events are called after ChildAdded events.

Conceptually, you attach a childAdded observer to a node along with a Value observer to that same node. The child added event will fire first and will iterate over each child so you can add it to an array datasource and then when complete the value event will fire to which you can reload a tableView or scroll to the last index since all the children had been loaded.

See my answer to [Loading Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082347/swift-firebase-loading-records-with-long-delay/41108155#41108155) for a coding example.

Comment: yes, observeSingleEventOfType save my time. It returns count at a node and I animates till all snapshots get equals to count. Thanks!!